# How to set package name in .ned file?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm new to omnet++. How to set the correct package name?

I created a new .ned file in omnet++5.4.1, but there was not a package name.And I type a name,the omnetide show me that declared package "org.car2x.veins.base.modules" does not match expected package "".
How to know which is the correct package name?
Thank you.
I use omnet++5.4.1 and veins 5a1.

Comment: OMNeT++ tells you the package name it expects (in this case: no package name, that is, no package declaration)

Answer (score 2):

The [OMNeT++ manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:packages) has an explanation for the definition of a package.

Directories in a NED source tree correspond to packages. If NED files are in the /a/b/c directory (where  is listed in NED path), then the package name is a.b.c. The package name has to be explicitly declared at the top of the NED files as well, like this:

```
package a.b.c;
```